# match value in column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dropdown like this

```
<select name="teamname">
    <option value="blank">Select</option>
     <option value="10">Tag Team 1</option><option value="11">Tag Team 2</option><option value="12">Team Pro</option><option value="13">Team Neo</option><option value="15">teamn</option><option value="16">Teamc</option><option value="17">Teamj</option>    </select>
```

and here is my database table image

[image]

I want to write sql query such that when it post id from dropdown it can match with column teamvs and display it  for eg if 10 so it show first row if 12 it will show 1st and 3rd row.

Comment: find in set will do.

Comment: what is the data type of `teamvs`?

Comment: find in set be working also i have one more column date and it contains value like 03-03-2015 is it possible to match month as same way  using month dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
$teamname = $_POST['teamname'];

$query="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE teamvs LIKE '$teamname,%' OR teamvs LIKE '%,$teamname'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Here, `$teamname` is the value selected by dropdown.

Comment: It will fetch all wildcards. like 100, 1000, 10000 and so on.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from TABLE where FIND_IN_SET('12',teamvs);
```

Comment: this seems to be working also i have one more column date and it contains value like 03-03-2015 is it possible to match month as same way

Comment: It will find any particular entry from comma separated entries.

Answer (score -1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE teamvs LIKE '%$a%';
```

$a stores the value of selected option.

Comment: what if teamvs is 100,12 and drop down value was 10?

Comment: Use: SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$a',teamvs);